# .FindControl() on GridView OnRowDeleted?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to FindControl() a HiddenField in my GridView's OnRowDeleted Event.

```
protected void gridviewPersonPhoto_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    //string strFileName = (the name of the file that needs to be deleted by System.IO
    //which i will know after I FindControl() the HiddenField in the deleted row that contains the name)
}


<asp:GridView id="gridviewPersonPhoto" DataKeyNames"PersonPhotoId"
    DataSourceId="sqldatasourcePersonPhoto" OnRowDeleted="gridviewPersonPhoto_RowDeleted">
    <TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenfieldFileName value='<%#Eval("FileName")%>' />
            <asp:Button ID="buttonDelete" CommandName="Delete" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" ImageUrl='<%# "~/pub/photo/"+(Eval("FileName")) %>'  runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you give and the html code here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code in Row_Deleted Event.

```
 GridViewRow gvRow= (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
 HiddenField HF = gvRow.FindControl("hiddenfieldFileName") as HiddenField;
```

Comment: This worked, but I soon found an easier solution: string FileName = e.Values[0].ToString(); But it requires me to use Bind instead of Eval though.